# $ \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} n \mathbb P \left ( \sup_{t \in [ 0 , T ]} S_t > n \right ) > 0 $ means $S_t$ is unbounded above almost surely.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, upper-lower-bounds

In a text book, the author states that $$ 
\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} n \mathbb P \left ( \sup_{t \in [ 0 , T ]} S_t > n \right ) > 0 
$$
means that $S_t$ is unbounded above almost surely. Can someone give some details please about that ?

It seems to me that being unbounded (above) $\iff $ $$ \forall n \in \mathbb R,  \mathbb P( S_t > n ) > 0 $$

> Are those statements really equivalent ?

Also, in the same way, one could read in the same text book that equation :

$$ 
\lim_{n \to \infty} n \mathbb P \left ( \inf_{t \in [ 0 , T ]} Z_t < - n \right ) = 0 
$$
What is the interpretation of that equation ? That the process $Z_t$ is bounded below ?

Comment: Unbounded a.s would be rather $$\mathbb P\left\{\forall n\in\mathbb N, \exists t_n\in [0,T], S_{t_n}>n\right\}=1.$$

Comment: What have you tried? I think the last equation can be interpreted as the "convergence speed" of $\mathbb P \left ( \inf_{t \in [ 0 , T ]} Z_t < - n \right )$ to $0$.